# Download file from external website with InAppBrowser - Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm working on android app and I use `Cordova and AngularJS`...

I want to open external link with `InAppBrowser` and allow the user to download file from a link inside this site...

When I click the button that should open the `InAppBrowser` it's opens the website but when I click on download link inside this site, nothing really happens...

The app have

```
 "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

permission

Thanks :)

Comment: The InAppBrowser can't download files.

Comment: So my only option is to use the browser of the device?

Comment: I haven't tested ist, but there are plugins to open another webview in cordova. Maybe that works.

Comment: Whats the plugin name? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: http://plugreg.com/search?q=webview

Comment: I tried 2 of the plugins there, and both have the same error when i compiled the app... The compiler cannot import: org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient and org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient

Comment: There is a plugin called FileTransfer that allows you to upload and download files.

Comment: I know, but I can't know the link for download because the link is from external website...

Comment: I'm sorry, that is explained in you're question but I had read it too fast.

Comment: Hi, I have the same situation. I have access to both website and app code. Did you find any way to make this work (on iOS too)?

Answer (score 4):

InAppBrowser doesn't allow download. You will need to modify plugin to allow it for downloading.

For android, inside `platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser`

method name `private void navigate(String url) {`

include

```
this.inAppWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

before this line `this.inAppWebView.requestFocus();`

again same code in the method `public void run() {`

after this segment

```
if (clearAllCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
            } else if (clearSessionCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();
            }

            inAppWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

in your .java file inside onCreate

```
appView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

add this two import `import android.net.Uri; import android.webkit.DownloadListener;`

Don't know about iOS

Comment: for appView and startActivity(i); is throwing error

Comment: It just doesn't work...